# Uploading files with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, http-headers

I am using CodeIgniter to download a file created by using the following code:

```
     header('Content-type: text/csv');

    header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=Pricemaster.csv');

    echo "Category,Supplier,Org Name,Org Modelno,Capacity,Our Modelno,China,OEM + Freight,Cost Price,USD %,USD price,GBP price,INR %,INR Conversion rate,INR price" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        $imp = implode(',', $val);
        echo $imp . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

I want to save this file to my upload folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write files to the server by using the [File Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html)

Firstly load the file helper:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

Then try this:

```
$file_path = './uploads/file.php'

$output = "Category,Supplier,Org Name,Org Modelno,Capacity,Our Modelno,China,OEM + Freight,Cost Price,USD %,USD price,GBP price,INR %,INR Conversion rate,INR price" . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($data as $val) {
    $imp = implode(',', $val);
    $output .= $imp . PHP_EOL;
}

if ( ! write_file($file_path, $output)) {
    echo 'Unable to write the file';
} else {
    echo 'File written!';
}
```

You'll want to change the file name / path accordingly. The data will obviously be your CSV output.

If the file writes successfully you can use this path to attach to your email.

Comment: I am aware of codeigniter upload library but the file is not sent from the form insted it is being crated using the code given above as it gives user to download it on the browser

Comment: So is the file opening in the browser rather than saving straight to their downloads folder?

Comment: it's not opening in the browser .it gives a option to save it in downloads folder . i want to upload it on server so that i can send it as a mail attachment

Comment: I've edited my original answer to suit your situation.

Comment: what is to be added in date variable as i query my database and the echo the field values to create csv

Comment: edited the original  question with code to download the csv file.

Comment: thanks for the reply i did it the other way...but will try this as well